# How to design a fixed login screens in react-native app(i.e) if the user tries to move or scroll the screen it does not move up or down

Tags: react-native

I need to know how the fixed login screens are shown in ui in mobile app(react-native).

(i.e) I have added the login screen if I make the screen to scroll it will move the screen up and down. I have written the code inside the views.

But many of the apps login screens not get moved in UI. How can I acheive this in my login screens.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use scroll view as the container of your Login form

```
 <View>
       <View>
        //Your login inputs and button
       </View>
       <ScrollView>
        //Others stuff that you want to add              
      </ScrollView>
</View>
```

That should work. I hope it helps.